# Trait objects force higher-ranked trait bounds, which break nested closures

Tags: rust, closures, trait-objects

I am in a situation where Rust makes me add a HRTB for a generic type that is used as argument in a trait object. But this HRTB makes nested closures not work.

Here's the trait I'm going to use to make a trait object `Box<dyn OpTrait>`:

```rust
trait OpTrait {}

struct Op<T>(T);

impl<T> OpTrait for Op<T> {}
```

Here's the struct with the trait objects:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Succ<'a, T>(T, &'a RefCell<Option<Box<dyn OpTrait>>>);

impl<'a, T: Clone> Succ<'a, T>
where
    for<'c> T: 'c, 
{
    fn trace(&self) -> Self {
        let b = Box::new(Op(self.0.clone()));
        self.1.borrow_mut().insert(b);
        Succ(self.0.clone(), self.1)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Zero;
```

And here's the function to put it all together:

```rust
fn nest<T: Clone, F>(f: F, t: &T) -> T
where
    for<'a> F: Fn(&Succ<'a, T>) -> Succ<'a, T>,
{
    let trace = RefCell::new(None);
    let nested = Succ(t.clone(), &trace);
    let result = f(&nested);
    result.0
}
```

I can use this like:

```rust
let input = Zero;
let result0 = nest(|n| n.trace(), &input);
```

which works.

But actually nesting the `nest` call stops working:

```rust
let result = nest(|n| nest(|nn| nn.trace(), n), &input);
```

```
  --> src/main.rs:46:37
   |
46 |     let result = nest(|n| nest(|nn| nn.trace(), n), &input);
   |                        -            ^^^^^^^^^^
   |                        |            |
   |                        |            `n` escapes the closure body here
   |                        |            argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
   |                        `n` is a reference that is only valid in the closure body
   |                        has type `&Succ<'1, Zero>`
```

Note:

Rust makes me add  `for<'c> T: 'c` in the `impl` for `Succ` - something to do with the trait object, I'm not exactly sure. This HRTB causes the problem with nested closures - without it in play, nested closures work fine:

```rust
// ok
let result2 = nest(|n| nest(|nn| nn.clone(), n), &input);
```

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a5fab1aca580e4fe630f91cfa7ac0639

EDIT: There's something with the 'a lifetime of the reference in Succ.

When I update that struct to remove the reference (and use Rc to support Clone):

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Succ<T>(T, Rc<dyn OpTrait>);
```

That works fine with the nesting, despite needing one more HRTB for `T` on `nest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following line:

```rust
let result1 = nest(|n| nest(|nn| nn.trace(), n), &input);
```

`n` has type `&Succ<'_, Zero>` due to `nest`'s definition, and for the same reason `nn` has type `&Succ<'_, &Succ<'_, Zero>>` (all the hidden lifetimes are different because you didn't specify lifetimes with the same parameter in the arguments of the `Fn` bound. This is not important though).

You're then trying to call `.trace()` on `nn`, which requires the bound `for<'c> T: 'c`. This bound is essentially the same as `T: 'static`, to see this you can just take `'c = 'static`, which must be valid because your bound is required for every possible lifetime `'c`. In this call the `T` from the definition of `trace` is actually `&Succ<'_, Zero>`, which however contains unknown lifetimes and thus is not `'static` and the bound `for<'c> T: 'c` is not satisfied.

The reason `result0` works is because you have a `&Succ<'_, Zero>`, where the `T` in `.trace()` is `Zero`, which is `'static`, so everything is fine.

Meanwhile in `result2` you're not calling `.trace()` which is the reason the `'static` bound was needed before, and thus that also works.

The fundamental problem in your code is that `Box<dyn OpTrait>` is implicitly a `Box<dyn OpTrait + 'static>`, while you actually want a `Box<dyn OpTrait + 'lifetime_of_t>`. It is natural then to introduce a lifetime `'t` to use in the `Box` and to bound `T` by. That is, changing `Succ`'s definition to:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Succ<'a, 't, T: 't>(T, &'a RefCell<Option<Box<dyn OpTrait + 't>>>);
```

and then updating the other methods to add `'t` lifetimes and `T: 't` bounds whenever needed.

Here's the complete fixed code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1fe778d04c5801203111fa5ae558fcee

```rust
use std::{
    cell::RefCell,
    fmt::Debug,
};


trait OpTrait {}

struct Op<T>(T);

impl<T> OpTrait for Op<T> {}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Succ<'a, 't, T: 't>(T, &'a RefCell<Option<Box<dyn OpTrait + 't>>>);

impl<'a, 't, T: Clone + 't> Succ<'a, 't, T>
{
    fn trace(&self) -> Self {
        let b = Box::new(Op(self.0.clone()));
        self.1.borrow_mut().insert(b);
        Succ(self.0.clone(), self.1)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Zero;

fn nest<'t, T: Clone + 't, F>(f: F, t: &T) -> T
where
    for<'a> F: Fn(&Succ<'a, 't, T>) -> Succ<'a, 't, T>,
{
    let trace = RefCell::new(None);
    let nested = Succ(t.clone(), &trace);
    let result = f(&nested);
    result.0
}

fn main() {
    let input = Zero;
    
    // ok
    let result0 = nest(|n| n.trace(), &input);
    dbg!(result0);
    
    // BOOOM
    let result1 = nest(|n| nest(|nn| nn.trace(), n), &input);
    dbg!(result1);
    
    // ok
    let result2 = nest(|n| nest(|nn| nn.clone(), n), &input);
    dbg!(result2);
}
```